# Reverse Caching Support using nginx

Tags: joomla-3.6, cache, nginx

How can I implement Reverse Caching Support using nginx mentioned in [Joomla 3.6 features](https://www.joomla.org/3/174-reverse-caching-support)?

> Joomla! 3.6 now supports reverse caching proxies like Varnish or an
>   NGINX caching proxy. These help to provide increased speed, more
>   performance and as a result better ranking in search engines.

Comment: Testing instructions for the pull request are here: https://gist.github.com/fevangelou/84d2ce05896cab5f730a